# PHP Listar la fecha de última modificación de un archivo

Tags: php

Quisiera pedir su apoyo ya que soy nuevo en Programación en PHP y estoy trabajando en un proyecto para poder listar en una tabla el contenido de un directorio ej. subidas, por fecha de última modificación.

El **problema** es que al listarlo **me lo muestra todo en una sola fila** y no por separado.

Espero me puedan entender y apoyar. Saludos.

```
<?php 
$directorio = getcwd()."/subidas";
$directorio_1 = opendir($directorio); //ruta actual
$files = array();
while (($archivo = readdir($directorio_1))) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
{
$archivo = $directorio."/".$archivo;
$files[] = $archivo;

}
for ($x=0; $x<count($files);$x++){

            echo date("d F Y H:i:s.", filectime($files[$x]))."\n";

        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que estás agregando un punto al final de una fecha (`d F Y H:i:s.`) podemos utilizar el mismo como separador para transformar ese `string` en un `array`.

```
    $dates = date("d F Y H:i:s.", filectime($files[$x]))."\n";
    $dates = explode(".", $dates);
    print_r($dates);
```

En estricto rigor el punto te servirá como separador de fechas y luego la función `explode` te permitirá separar las fechas por el punto.

Ahora solo te toca identificar que posición del `array` tiene la fecha de ultima modificación.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día muchas gracias por sus comentarios. He logrado que me muestre la fecha pero al quererlo mostrar en una tabla me muestra varias veces la fecha de un solo archivo, esto es Archivo A, se genero ej. 03/03/2020, pero el mismo Archivo A tiene la fecha anterior y 3 veces mas con distintas fechas por lo que no logro que solo me muestre una sola fecha. A continuación el código.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th width="7%">#</th>
  <th width="35%">Nombre del Archivo</th>
   <th width="35%">Fecha última modificación</th>
  <th width="13%">Descargar</th>
  <th width="10%">Eliminar</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
 header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
 $archivos = scandir("/var/www/html/WebTelynet/subidas/");
 $num=0;

     for ($i=2; $i<count($archivos); $i++)
 {$num++;
 ?>

 <?php 
 $directorio = getcwd()."/../subidas/";
 $directorio_1 = opendir($directorio); //ruta actual
 $files=array();
 $archivo1 = readdir($directorio_1);
 while ($archivo = $archivo1) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
 {
    $fichero = $archivo;
    $archivo = $directorio."/".$archivo;
 if (is_dir($archivo))//verificamos si es o no un directorio
 {
 //////        echo "[".$archivo . "]<br />"; //de ser un directorio lo envolvemos entre corchetes
 }
 else
 {
         //$files[] = $archivo;
         //$files[] = $archivos1;            
            $files[] = $fichero;             
         //$files[] = $directorio;           
         //$files[] = $directorio_1;             
         //$files[] = $archivo1;             
  }
  }

  for ($x=0; $x<count($files);$x++){
  $num1=0;
    ?>
  <p>  
  </p>

  <tr>
  <th scope="row"><?php echo $num;?></th>
  <td><?php echo $archivos[$i]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo date("d F Y H:i:s.", filectime($directorio."/".$files[$x])); ?> </td>
  <td><a title="Descargar Archivo" href="/var/www/html/WebTelynet/subidas/<?php echo $archivos[$i]; ?>" download="<?php echo $archivos[$i]; ?>" style="color: blue; font-size:18px;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a></td>
  <td><a title="Eliminar Archivo" href="Eliminar.php?miarchivo=/var/www/html/WebTelynet/subidas/<?php echo $archivos[$i]; ?>" style="color: red; font-size:18px;" onclick="return confirm('Esta seguro de eliminar el archivo?');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a></td>


    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```